# Rails-API How to test Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postman, rails-activestorage

I added Active Storage into my Rails API application and want to test it, but I don't know how to do it. I was trying send file with JSON data in Postman, but JSON data doesn't send correctly or I am doing something wrong. I did it like that:
[Image from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdJlg.png)

Is there any option to send request with file and JSON data without creating any view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, an upload can't be done via an API rest way. You need to use `enctype: multipart/form-data`  as regular `POST` done via form.

In your screenshot you are already sending as form-post, because you chose to send via `form-data`. This is why your json isn't properly parsed by rails.

If you want to upload an image and post data in the same request you will need to break your json attributes into form data fields like:

```
data[name]=asaa
data[last_name]=foo
...
```

Or, you can send a JSON in your `data` field and do the manual parsing when fetching in controller like:

```rb
def upload
  file = params[:file]
  data = parsed_params_data!(params)

  # do your magic
end

def parsed_params_data!(params)
  JSON.parse(params[:data])
end
```